# WebService call using R

Tags: r, web-services

I have a list of Port origin and destination location for marine transportation.I want to estimate the average time taken to travel from one port to another. I just came across the webservice request provided by [Vesseldistance.com](http://www.vesseldistance.com/?page_id=115)

How to call this web service from R and Is it possible to send bulk of port origin and destination locations to estimate the avg time taken to travel?

Comment: if they supply an API you are likely to be able to use a package like `httr` to do `POST` and `GET` requests

Comment: I'd be wary about using an API that has you putting your credentials in a bare GET request like this one does.

Comment: Is there any other API available to find the distance between the port?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example using `httr` you can wrap their sample `GET` request into a call form `R`:

```
httr::GET("http://vesseltracker.com/FILE?user=foo&pass=bar&fromLon=9.9&fromLat=53.54&toLon=47&toLat=11&speed=20&startTime=1&numOfRoutes=ALL")
```

Unfortunately their API is not documented very well.